# Why does YouTube playlist restart in the middle?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I'm watching a playlist of 130 entries from start to finish - or so I thought - when after watching the 46th entry I'm thrown back to the first. I was expecting to see the 47th.

When I tap "next" I go to the beginning of the playlist. When I tap on the 47th entry I go to the 47th entry.

I don't understand why it works like this?

I have been trying to figure out the purpose and usage of YouTube playlists for a long time but it keeps eluding me with unexpected behavior.

Using Safari for iOS 10.

[The playlist](https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PL5BxQPb93TvlplfFgVjQ7gQIvoXUKuBQM&params=EAEYATgBSAFYLmILS2NQUmZLaWMtSnNoLA%253D%253D&v=aa_ZVp4413Y&mode=NORMAL)

*Before tapping next on the left.* *After tapping next on the right:*

[image: Before tapping next] [image: After tapping next]

Comment: @pnuts https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/dash-and-em-dash otherwise good, in the absence of markdown for annotating individual pictures.

Comment: @pnuts You're welcome, but I'm not sure I did you a kindness. From now on you'll be bothered whenever someone uses a hyphen where there should be a dash, and by the fact that you have no idea how to type one on a regular keyboard. Welcome to the world of straight lines of different lengths https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen